# How to deform/stretch a Mesh along Curve flow

Tags: geometry-nodes

Unfortunately I'm not such pro in Geometry-Nodes and Vector Math.
Maybe someone here can give an example.

I have e.g. this curve and with Sample Curve some points get moved along the curve flow. And Icosphere Instances are on these Points.

It would be cooler, if the Icosphere Meshs would deform along the curve tangents, so it get stretched along curve flow. Like Fire particles instead of droplets.
[image]

[Example File from an asset pack: Particle Flow](https://easyupload.io/rjhqx0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I tried by positioning particles on some curve factors, then realizing them and only then rotating by aligned Euler to tangent vector, but this tangent would be offset by the (captured before instantiation) $x$ coordinate. Main problem: the particle overlaps self, and the calculations weren't too precise, just playing around:

[image: worms, bleh!]

So maybe beveling a curve with changing radius (sometimes $0$) is a better approach:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish